# gRPC-Java ssl server side authentication certificate generation

Tags: openssl, grpc, grpc-java

I have been trying to set up server side authentication with ssl for a simple Java gRPC application. I am using certstrap to generate the keys and certificates as follows:

```
# Create CA
$ certstrap init --common-name "GRPC"
# Create cert for host using DNS name
$ certstrap request-cert --common-name sdl10236.labs.teradata.com
$ certstrap sign server.com --CA "GRPC"
# gives the following files:
$ GRPC.crl  GRPC.crt  GRPC.key  server.crt  server.csr  server.key
```

I have the following java code that I have pieced together from their hello world example and some of their Unit tests as I could not find a complete example of how to do this.

```
private SslProvider sslProvider = SslProvider.OPENSSL;

...

this.clientContextBuilder = GrpcSslContexts.configure(SslContextBuilder.forClient(), this.sslProvider);
try {
    this.serverCertFile = this.loadCert("server.crt");
    this.serverPrivateKeyFile = this.loadCert("server.key");
    this.serverTrustedCaCerts = new X509Certificate[]{this.loadX509Cert("GRPC.crt")};
} catch (IOException ex) {
    logger.warning("Error occurred loading certificate files.");
    ex.getMessage();
    ex.printStackTrace();
} catch (CertificateException cex) {
    logger.warning("Error occurred loading the x509 cert.");
}

...

this.server = serverBuilder(0, this.serverCertFile, this.serverPrivateKeyFile, this.serverTrustedCaCerts).forPort(port).addService(new HelloServiceGrpc.HelloServiceImplBase() { ... }

...

private File loadCert(String name) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(GrpcServer.class.getResourceAsStream("/certs/" + name));
    File tmpFile = File.createTempFile(name, "");
    tmpFile.deleteOnExit();

    OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(tmpFile));
    try {
        int b;
        while ((b = in.read()) != -1) {
            os.write(b);
        }

        os.flush();
    } finally {
        in.close();
        os.close();
    }

    return tmpFile;
}

private X509Certificate loadX509Cert(String fileName) throws CertificateException, IOException {
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    logger.info("" + fileName);
    InputStream in = GrpcServer.class.getResourceAsStream("/certs/" + fileName);
    if (in != null) {
        logger.info("Inputstream is defined.");
    }
    try {
        return (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(in);
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
}

private ServerBuilder<?> serverBuilder(int port, File serverCertChainFile,
        File serverPrivateKeyFile, X509Certificate[] serverTrustedCaCerts) throws IOException {
    SslContextBuilder sslContextBuilder = SslContextBuilder.forServer(serverCertChainFile, serverPrivateKeyFile);
    GrpcSslContexts.configure(sslContextBuilder, sslProvider);
    sslContextBuilder.trustManager(serverTrustedCaCerts).clientAuth(ClientAuth.REQUIRE);

    return NettyServerBuilder.forPort(port).sslContext(sslContextBuilder.build());
}
```

When I read the certificates and keys in the program is failing on the x509 certificate reading.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File does not contain valid private key: /tmp/GRPC.key5252344955683539009
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.keyManager(SslContextBuilder.java:267)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.keyManager(SslContextBuilder.java:222)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.forServer(SslContextBuilder.java:54)
at com.teradata.grpc.GrpcServer.serverBuilder(GrpcServer.java:152)
at com.teradata.grpc.GrpcServer.start(GrpcServer.java:69)
at com.teradata.grpc.GrpcServer.main(GrpcServer.java:111)
Caused by: java.security.KeyException: could not find a PKCS #8 private key in input stream (see http://netty.io/wiki/sslcontextbuilder-and-private-key.html for more information)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.PemReader.readPrivateKey(PemReader.java:128)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.PemReader.readPrivateKey(PemReader.java:109)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.toPrivateKey(SslContext.java:1014)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.keyManager(SslContextBuilder.java:265)
... 5 more
```

My real question here is what is the proper way to generate the keys? I have been all over the documentation and have read that the expected format is PEM but certstrap generates the .crt files in PEM format. I am not sure which files I am supposed to be reading in and I have not found and example in the documentation that works through generating the proper keys.

I should note that the keys generated by certstrap work in C++ but not Java.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going to the URL in the error message seems to give a good clue: http://netty.io/wiki/sslcontextbuilder-and-private-key.html

certstrap generates keys that start with:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I see that grpc-java's test keys start with:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Running the command Netty documented appears to convert to the same format used in the test keys:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in server.key -out server.key2
```

(Also discussed at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/grpc-io/5uAK5c9rTHw)

Comment: This worked! Thanks Eric! I voted but I don't have a high enough rep. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Polyglot has an integration test which does client and server TLS auth[1]. It also documents the exact commands to run in order to generate the certs[2].

You should be able to swipe some code from there. Does that help?

[1] https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/polyglot/blob/master/src/main/java/me/dinowernli/grpc/polyglot/testing/TestServer.java#L118

[2] https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/polyglot/tree/master/src/main/java/me/dinowernli/grpc/polyglot/testing/test-certificates

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dino but I had the wrong files loaded in the wrong order along with Eric's answer. I was able to get it to work.